# BCP command is not working in Windows 2012 R2

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, cmd, bcp

I have a .bat file where I wrote some statement to read a text file and insert a data into the SQL Server table through BCP commands. When I run this file in Windows 7 or Windows Server 2003 it works fine. But when I run this batch file on Windows Server 2012 R2, it does not work. Any ideas?

Comment: Is this required SQL Client to run the BCP?

Comment: isn't BCP a sql server stuff? is the server installed the proper SQL Server?